# SAS timestamp from scientific notation to yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss

Tags: sql, database, sas

**Problem:**

My timestamp is being displayed in scientific notation. I would like to display the column without scientific notation, and create a second column formatted as a long date, yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss.

**Steps taken:**

I've already converted the column from a UNIX Epoch (1960) timestamp to SAS time (1970) timestamp. But scientific notation persists. I tried date20. doesn't do the trick, either.

[Timestamp in Scientific Notation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YfJN.jpg)

My current insufficient code fails to format the timestamp column as a date.

```
proc print data=heart._23a;
    format timestamp date9.;
run;
```

**Results:**

It results in no errors, but it [redimensions my matrix to a 1x3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsv9l.jpg). I need to obtain a matrix of the same dimension, just with a reformatted timestamp. I appreciate any help, but please keep it *simple*, I am in unknown territory!

Comment: SAS datetime values are the number of seconds from 1/1/1960 (not 1970). The default format for numbers is BEST12.  If your values are larger so that 12 digits is not enough then just use a different format. Such as F20.

Answer (score 6):

`datetime17.` is the standard timestamp format in SAS, though you have many other choices as well.  [`ymddttm.`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003172040.htm) is the closest to what you're looking for, I believe.

One important distinction here:  SAS has two concepts, `date` and `datetime`.  `date` is number of days since 1/1/1960 *and has no time part*, while `datetime` is number of seconds since 1/1/1960 00:00:00 and has both time and date.  You can use `datepart` to convert datetime -> date, or `dhms` to convert date -> datetime.

Your question also seems to get the two epochs backwards.  UNIX epoch is 1970.  SAS epoch is 1960.

Finally, if you want to display the raw number of seconds, use `w.d` format instead of `bestw.d` format - `format timestampvar 14.` for example, where `w` is number of characters (digits) wide total including decimal.